# How to seperate Angular html and Script code

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a angular frontend project, I have a dashboard component where I have an sidebar inside, but the code has its script tag and html in the same file. I would like to seperate them in order to have less code.

I tried including these scripts with path in my angular.json but it did not get recognized, and I did not know what else I could try. My html code looks like this, and I would like to seperate the Head tag and script tags.

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="Responsive sidebar template with sliding effect and dropdown menu based on bootstrap 3">
  <title>Sidebar template</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>
<moniesta-client-navbar></moniesta-client-navbar>

<body>
<div class="page-wrapper chiller-theme toggled">
  <a id="show-sidebar" class="btn btn-sm btn-dark" href="#">
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
  <nav id="sidebar" class="sidebar-wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar-content">
      <div class="sidebar-brand">
        <a href="#">pro sidebar</a>
        <div id="close-sidebar">
          <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar-header">
        <div class="user-pic">
          <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/azouaoui-med/pro-sidebar-template/gh-pages/src/img/user.jpg"
               alt="User picture">
        </div>
        <div class="user-info">
          <span class="user-name">Jhon
            <strong>Smith</strong>
          </span>
          <span class="user-role">Administrator</span>
          <span class="user-status">
            <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
            <span>Online</span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- sidebar-header  -->
      <div class="sidebar-search">
        <div>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control search-menu" placeholder="Search...">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <span class="input-group-text">
                <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- sidebar-search  -->
      <div class="sidebar-menu">
        <ul>
          <li class="header-menu">
            <span>General</span>
          </li>
          <li class="sidebar-dropdown">
            <a href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
              <span>Dashboard</span>
              <span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning">New</span>
            </a>
            <div class="sidebar-submenu">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Dashboard 1
                    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-success">Pro</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Dashboard 2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Dashboard 3</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="sidebar-dropdown">
            <a href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
              <span>E-commerce</span>
              <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger">3</span>
            </a>
            <div class="sidebar-submenu">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Products

                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Orders</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Credit cart</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="sidebar-dropdown">
            <a href="#">
              <i class="far fa-gem"></i>
              <span>Components</span>
            </a>
            <div class="sidebar-submenu">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">General</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Panels</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Tables</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Icons</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Forms</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="sidebar-dropdown">
            <a href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-chart-line"></i>
              <span>Charts</span>
            </a>
            <div class="sidebar-submenu">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Pie chart</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Line chart</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Bar chart</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Histogram</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="sidebar-dropdown">
            <a href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
              <span>Maps</span>
            </a>
            <div class="sidebar-submenu">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Google maps</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Open street map</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="header-menu">
            <span>Extra</span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-book"></i>
              <span>Documentation</span>
              <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Beta</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
              <span>Calendar</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-folder"></i>
              <span>Examples</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- sidebar-menu  -->
    </div>
    <!-- sidebar-content  -->
    <div class="sidebar-footer">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-bell"></i>
        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning notification">3</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-success notification">7</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
        <span class="badge-sonar"></span>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-power-off"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <footer class="text-center">
    <div class="mb-2">
      <small>
        © 2020 made with <i class="fa fa-heart" style="color:red"></i> by - <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://azouaoui.netlify.com">
        Mohamed Azouaoui
      </a>
      </small>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="https://github.com/azouaoui-med" target="_blank">
        <img alt="GitHub followers" src="https://img.shields.io/github/followers/azouaoui-med?label=github&style=social" />
      </a>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/azouaoui_med" target="_blank">
        <img alt="Twitter Follow" src="https://img.shields.io/twitter/follow/azouaoui_med?label=twitter&style=social" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <!-- sidebar-wrapper  -->
  <main class="page-content">


  </main>
  <!-- page-content" -->
</div>
<!-- page-wrapper -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the packages.
Here you have the packages at your script.

```
npm i jquery
npm i bootstrap
npm i @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome
https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome
```

And do not forget to add the `bootstrap` & `jquery` at the `angular.json`

```
 "styles": [
    "src/styles.css",
     "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
 ],
  "scripts": [
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
   "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
 ]
```

And I suggest you to separate your code in different components.
Thats you make your code more readable and you can faster fix a bug or find what you want.